# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, owin

I got the "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin' or one of its dependencies."

My scenario is, i have multiple asp.net mvc projects in my solution, when i pick any one of the project as startup it is working fine but at the same time the other project got this error. All the projects are hosted as different applications in IIS for this solution.

Comment: Use fuselogvw to check what exactly it fails to load. Also check bin folder in your not-setted-as-startup project. Does it contain Microsoft.Owin? Third. Have you used nuget to install this dependency? Fourth. How do you start second project?

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your reply. yes it contains Microsoft.Owin in not set as start up project. I have used the nuget to install these packages. All projects are configured in IIS, so i was using those projects using url

Comment: Then fuselogvw should show more details about what happens

Answer (score 0):

I guess, somehow you are missing the required DLLs.

Please refer this [article](http://www.karthikscorner.com/sharepoint/developing-deploying-signalr-application-iis/) to see if it helps.